# Microsoft outlook appointments events

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

Is there anyway to mark any appointments automatically with red in case of refused or green in case of accepted and prevent it being deleted from the calendar when refused?
I thought searching and programming it with VBA but I'm kind of lost on this and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark it with the appropriate color category. You can watch incoming messages in the Inbox folder using Items.ItemAdd event on the Inbox folder and process the meeting updates for the appointments.